# Calculating system availability against SLA

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Looking for some advice on how to approach this

The application has system outages logged in an outages table.  The outage contains date/time for outage start and outage end as well as a description.

There is also a joining table that links the outage ID with the system IDs that were affected by the outage.

Currently, the availability is calculated on a 24 x 7 basis, with the following:

```
$agreed_seconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * $availability->report_date->daysInMonth;

$availability = round((($agreed_seconds - $outage->duration) / $agreed_seconds) * 100, 2);
```

If a system's availability SLA is only business hours and not 24 x 7, an outage that occurs between 2am and 3am should not be included in the availability calculation.

How would you do this calculation and store the data (i.e. only as an availability percentage or additional columns in the outage table itself)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ishegg in this related question [Using PHP Carbon, remove time in seconds where two time periods overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508230/using-php-carbon-remove-time-in-seconds-where-two-time-periods-overlap/46508378#46508378) this has now been resolved.

Once the number of seconds outside of the SLA have been subtracted, the real duration can be used to calculate the availability percentage.